# C++ Simple Reflection without Macros: Print Variable Name and Its Value

Tags: c++, reflection, macros

Is there a non-macro way in C++ of printing a variable name with its value. Here is the macro way:

```
#define SHOW(a) std::cout << #a << ": " << (a) << std::endl
```

PS: I'm using Linux and do not need a cross-platform solution

Comment: why do you need it without macro? You want to do it runtime?

Comment: @balki: How does that matter?

Comment: @baiki, no, not runtime, but I do want to avoid using macros in this case (and in general) because of name collisions and lack of overloading functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic symbols, but then it will only work in shared libraries or executables compiled with the -rdynamic flag. And it will recognize just global variables with default dynamic visibility.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

int NameMe = 42;

const char *GetName(const void *ptr)
{
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(ptr, &info))
        return info.dli_sname;
    else
        return NULL;
}

    template<typename T>
void Dump(const T &t)
{
    const char *name = GetName(&t);
    if (name)
        std::cout << name;
    else
        std::cout << "<unknown>";
    std::cout << ": " << t << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    int NoName = 33;
    Dump(NameMe);
    Dump(NoName);
    return 0;
}

$ g++ dump.cpp -ldl -rdynamic
$ ./a.out
NameMe: 42
<unknown>: 33
```

Answer (score 6):

No, C++ does not support reflection and the only way of doing this (as far as I know) are with macros.

Comment: By the way, I'm well aware that C++ does not natively support reflection, however, I thought there might be some powerful solutions that are not cross-platform that I didn't know about.

Comment: @Lex: I realize that ; that's why I specifically mentioned that it's not possible without macros (your only constraint).

Comment: @AlanTuring reflection in other languages likely relies on macros at some level. Python itself is a macro.  Call it by another name, but an interpretation layer or intermediate compile grants properties similar to macros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; in C++17 you can use PFR (in C++17 mode) to get nontrivial levels of non-macro reflection. There are related mechanisms for reflecting the "string-value" of an enum.

1. See https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get ;
2. And https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum .

Answer (score 0):

No way.

Without macro, you've to do this:

```
std::cout <<"a : " << a << std::endl;
```

No other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have all your classes derive from a common ancestor, you can provide a virtual function that accomplishes this. I haven't tried this template, it might not work - some feedback would be appreciated.

```
struct Reflector
{
    virtual void Show() = 0;
};
template<class a, char name[]>
struct ReflectorImpl : public Reflector
{
    virtual void Show()
    {
        std::cout << name << ": " << *this << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyClass: public ReflectorImpl<MyClass, "MyClass">
{
};
```

Comment: I don't know if the cout of `*this` will work without defining `operator<<` on the class. I would implement `Show()` in the base class and force (via a pure abstract method in the base class) the subclasses to define `operator<<` or some sort of ToString method.